# JQuery Ajax, root element not formed

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, api

So i've been taking my first dive into javascript dealing with jquery in particular.

I get this error when trying to use the built in $.ajax() to load up html into a div on he same page. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#searchbtn').on('submit', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: $(this).val()  
        }).done(function(data) {$(#mainView).append(data)});
        });


    });
});
```

Here is the corresponding HTML. Also to note that this is being passed through XML "CDATA".

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js></script>
<div id ="container">

<h1 id="titleLogo">Web+</h1>

<div class="bar" id="navBar">
    <form name="urlBar" action="" method="GET">
        <label for="urlsearch">Let's browse together: <input type="url" name="url" id="url" value="http://www.google.com"></label>
        <label for="searchbtn"><input type="submit" value="go" id="searchbtn"></label>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="bar" id="userBar"></div>

<div class="view" id="mainView"></div>
<div class="bar" id="viewsBar"></div>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check that you have 1 redundant `});` and `$("#mainView")` not `$(#mainView)`

Comment: My answer will work for your html http://stackoverflow.com/a/17160868/880434

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#searchbtn').on('submit', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: $(this).val()  
        }).done(function(data) {$('#mainView').append(data)});
        });


    });
```

Hope it helps! :D